# LDA topic modeling input data

Tags: python, twitter, lda, topic-modeling

I am new to python. I just started working on a project to use LDA topic modeling on tweets. I am trying the the following code:

This example uses an online dataset . I have a csv file that includes the tweets that I need to use. Can anybody tell me how can I use my local file? How should I make my own vocab and titles?

I couldn't find a tutorial that explains how to prepare materials for the LDA. They all assume that you already know how to do so.

```html
from __future__ import division, print_function

import numpy as np
import lda
import lda.datasets


# document-term matrix

X = lda.datasets.load_reuters()
print("type(X): {}".format(type(X)))
print("shape: {}\n".format(X.shape))

# the vocab
vocab = lda.datasets.load_reuters_vocab()
print("type(vocab): {}".format(type(vocab)))
print("len(vocab): {}\n".format(len(vocab)))

# titles for each story
titles = lda.datasets.load_reuters_titles()
print("type(titles): {}".format(type(titles)))
print("len(titles): {}\n".format(len(titles)))


doc_id = 0
word_id = 3117

print("doc id: {} word id: {}".format(doc_id, word_id))
print("-- count: {}".format(X[doc_id, word_id]))
print("-- word : {}".format(vocab[word_id]))
print("-- doc  : {}".format(titles[doc_id]))


model = lda.LDA(n_topics=20, n_iter=500, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)


topic_word = model.topic_word_ 
print("type(topic_word): {}".format(type(topic_word)))
print("shape: {}".format(topic_word.shape))


for n in range(5):
    sum_pr = sum(topic_word[n,:])
    print("topic: {} sum: {}".format(n, sum_pr))


n = 5
for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
    topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n+1):-1]
    print('*Topic {}\n- {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))


doc_topic = model.doc_topic_
print("type(doc_topic): {}".format(type(doc_topic)))
print("shape: {}".format(doc_topic.shape))
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this comes a bit late, but hope it helps.You firstly have to understand that LDA is applicable on the DTM (Document Term Matrix) only.  So, I propose you run the following steps:

1. Load your csv file
2. Extract the requisite tweets from the file
3. Clean the data
4. Create a dictionary containing each word of the corpus generated
5. Build a TDM structure
6. Fit the structure to your data file
7. Obtain the vocabulary - the TDM features (words)
8. Continue using the code above

Here, can provide this code to help you get started -

```
token_dict = {}

for i in range(len(txt1)):
    token_dict[i] = txt1[i]

len(token_dict)


print("\n Build DTM")
%time tf = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

print("\n Fit DTM")
%time tfs1 = tf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())

# set the number of topics to look for
num = 8

model = lda.LDA(n_topics=num, n_iter=500, random_state=1)

# we fit the DTM not the TFIDF to LDA
print("\n Fit LDA to data set")
%time model.fit_transform(tfs1)

print("\n Obtain the words with high probabilities")
%time topic_word = model.topic_word_  # model.components_ also works

print("\n Obtain the feature names")
%time vocab = tf.get_feature_names()
```